# c# Console Application How to enter multiple lines of input and not just take the first line in ReadLine?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am creating a program in c# where it will read multiple lines and the read the lines one at a time and outputs some info. The code is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string info1Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] theInfo1 = info1Stuff.Split(',');            

            string info2Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] theInfo2 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
            string info3Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] theInfo3 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
            string info4Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] theInfo4 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
            string info5Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] theInfo5 = info1Stuff.Split(',');

            NavigationInfo info1 = new NavigationInfo(theInfo1[0], theInfo1[1], theInfo1[2], theInfo1[3], Convert.ToDouble(theInfo1[4]));

            info1.calculateDistance();
            info1.calculateTime();
            info1.calculateCost();

            NavigationInfo info2 = new NavigationInfo(theInfo2[0], theInfo2[1], theInfo2[2], theInfo2[3], Convert.ToDouble(theInfo2[4]));

            info2.calculateDistance();
            info2.calculateTime();
            info2.calculateCost();

            NavigationInfo info3 = new NavigationInfo(theInfo3[0], theInfo3[1], theInfo3[2], theInfo3[3], Convert.ToDouble(theInfo3[4]));

            info3.calculateDistance();
            info3.calculateTime();
            info3.calculateCost();

            NavigationInfo info4 = new NavigationInfo(theInfo4[0], theInfo4[1], theInfo4[2], theInfo4[3], Convert.ToDouble(theInfo4[4]));

            info4.calculateDistance();
            info4.calculateTime();
            info4.calculateCost();

            NavigationInfo info5 = new NavigationInfo(theInfo5[0], theInfo5[1], theInfo5[2], theInfo5[3], Convert.ToDouble(theInfo5[4]));

            info5.calculateDistance();
            info5.calculateTime();
            info5.calculateCost();

            Console.WriteLine(info1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(info2.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(info3.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(info4.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(info5.ToString());
```

But wen I enter all the data, it shows up with the output for the first line of input 5 times, not 5 different output lines. So it is basically forgetting lines 2-5 and only using the first line of input and outputs this 5 times

Please let me know

Thanks
Rohan

Comment: Look carefully at the target of your `Split` calls.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
string info1Stuff = Console.ReadLine();

string[] theInfo1 = info1Stuff.Split(',');            


string info2Stuff = Console.ReadLine();

string[] theInfo2 = info2Stuff.Split(',');

string info3Stuff = Console.ReadLine();

string[] theInfo3 = info3Stuff.Split(',');

string info4Stuff = Console.ReadLine();

string[] theInfo4 = info4Stuff.Split(',');

string info5Stuff = Console.ReadLine();

string[] theInfo5 = info5Stuff.Split(',');
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I spent so much time on this project and I didnt want to give up just cause of a simple mistake like this.

Answer (score 1):

Handling five different info bits individually seems to makes things cumbersome. Use an array for `info`. This enables you to use a loop.

```
const N = 5;  // Number of input lines.

var info = new NavigationInfo[N];  // Here an array is handier as individual variables.

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     // You don't need any index here; you can reuse the same variable.
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Same here. You can reuse this array.
    string[] parts = input.Split(',');

    var navInfo = new NavigationInfo(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3],
                                     Convert.ToDouble(parts[4]));
    navInfo.calculateDistance();
    navInfo.calculateTime();
    navInfo.calculateCost();

    info[i] = navInfo;
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(info[i]);  // Console.WriteLine calls ToString automatically.
}
```

One of many software development principles is named **[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)**: **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself. Handling five input lines individually repeats the almost same code 5 times. This is a lot typing and gives you 5 times the opportunity to make errors. In addition, if you need to adapt you code later, you'll need to do it 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
        string[] theInfo1 = info1Stuff.Split(',');            

        string info2Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo2 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
        string info3Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo3 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
        string info4Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo4 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
        string info5Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo5 = info1Stuff.Split(',');
```

to this:

```
        string[] theInfo1 = info1Stuff.Split(',');            

        string info2Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo2 = info2Stuff.Split(',');
        string info3Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo3 = info3Stuff.Split(',');
        string info4Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo4 = info4Stuff.Split(',');
        string info5Stuff = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] theInfo5 = info5Stuff.Split(',');
```

it's a simple copy/paste error.

Comment: Thank you. I was working on this for a while, so maybe Im just working too long.

Comment: Hi @ChefBrohan, yes, working too much has of those things ;) Even not being ast enough, consider upvoting my answer ;) Good luck! And get a rest ;)